# Extending a distribution to the real line

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let

$$u=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\delta^{(k)}_{\frac{1}{k}} \quad ,$$

where $\delta_x$ is the standard Dirac delta distribution $\delta_x(\phi)=\phi(x)$.

The distribution above acts on elements of $C^\infty_c((0,\infty))$ via

$$u(\phi)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\phi^{(k)}\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\quad\ ,$$

using the standard formula of derivating a distribution via integration by parts.

I'm trying to see why there can't be a distribution $v$ such that $u=v$ in a neighborhood of $0$, that is, such that $u(\phi)=v(\phi)$ for every $\phi$ with compact support contained in say, the compact $[-1,1]$. It seems that if we can find a $\phi$ such that $\phi(x)=\exp(x)$ for $|x|<1$, then

$$u(\phi)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\exp\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)>\sum_{k=1}^\infty\exp(0)\ ,$$

which shows in particular that such extension cannot satisfy the seminorm condition for a distribution. However, I don't see how we can take such $\phi$ to be smooth *and* compactly supported on $[-1,1]$ (how do we make $\exp(x)$ fall smoothly outside $[-1,1]$ for example?). Also, I am not sure about the inequality above: the *absolute value* of $u(\phi)$ is bounded by $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\exp(\frac{1}{k})$, and the sum is actually finite because $\phi$ supposedly has compact support, but the argument still doesn't seem right. What am I missing?

Comment: What order will the distribution have on $[-1,1]$?

Comment: Infinite, right?

Comment: If it's even continuous, since by the inequality above the seminorm condition gets blown up...

Comment: Correct, the order is infinite on the compact interval $[-1,1].$ What do we know about the order of a distribution on a compact set? It must be finite for the "distribution candidate" to be continuous. Thus, this extension does not define a distribution.

Comment: What's special about the origin, then? If I understand the argument, we use a bump function to transform the distribution candidate $v$ into a compactly supported distribution in every compact, so that $v$ is (restricted to) a compactly supported distribution with infinite order in that compact, which can't happen.

Comment: Taking $\mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}$ to be the "rect function", i.e. having value $1$ on $[-1,1]$ and $0$ outside of $[-1,1]$ and $\rho_\epsilon \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ with $\int \rho_\epsilon(x) \, dx = 1$ and having support $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ then the convolution $\mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}*\rho_\epsilon$ is a $C^\infty_c$ function with value $1$ on $[-1+\epsilon,1-\epsilon]$ and support $[-1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon].$ Multiplying this with $e^x$ gives you the type of function you are looking for.